# Unable to export hive table to mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to export a hive table to mysql database whose data is tab delimited as stored in HDFS but the job is failing every time after mapper phase.

I have referred to many link and resources and cross checked my export command like export-directory, table name and other factors. Also the schema of both the tables are same but still didn't have any idea why the jobs are failing every time.

Schema in hive :

```
display_id int
employment_type string
edu_qualification string
marital_status string
job_type string
working_hours_per_week int
country string
salary string
```

Schema in Mysql

```
display_id  int 
employment_type varchar(100)    
edu_qualification   varchar(100)    
marital_status  varchar(100)
job_type    varchar(100)    
working_hours_per_week  int 
country varchar(100)    
salary  varchar(100)
```

Command used for exporting table

```
sqoop export \
--connect <<jdbcURL>> \
--username root \ 
--password **** \
--table census_table \
--export-dir <<hdfs_dir>> \ 
--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' \
--columns "display_id,employment_type,edu_qualification,marital_status,job_type,working_hours_per_week,country,salary" \
--num-mappers 1
```

Sample data in file

```
39  StateGov    BachelorDegree  Unmarried   Clerical    45  US  <=55K
```

logs of export operation :

```
Warning: HBASE_HOME and HBASE_VERSION not set.
Warning: HCAT_HOME not set
Warning: HCATALOG_HOME does not exist HCatalog imports will fail.
Please set HCATALOG_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: ACCUMULO_HOME not set.
Warning: ZOOKEEPER_HOME not set.
Warning: HBASE_HOME does not exist HBase imports will fail.
Please set HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: ACCUMULO_HOME does not exist Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: ZOOKEEPER_HOME does not exist Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
20/04/24 12:03:59 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
20/04/24 12:03:59 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
20/04/24 12:03:59 WARN sqoop.SqoopOptions: Character argument '\t' has multiple characters; only the first will be used.
20/04/24 12:04:00 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
20/04/24 12:04:00 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual l
20/04/24 12:04:01 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `census_table` AS t LIMIT 1
20/04/24 12:04:01 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `census_table` AS t LIMIT 1
20/04/24 12:04:01 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is C:\hadoop-2.10.0
Note: \tmp\sqoop-Anand\compile\8987413e3b916524daa02124c4829b87\census_table.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
20/04/24 12:04:08 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: \tmp\sqoop-Anand\compile\8987413e3b916524daa02124c4829b87\census_table.jar
20/04/24 12:04:08 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of census_table
20/04/24 12:04:08 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
20/04/24 12:04:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
20/04/24 12:04:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
20/04/24 12:04:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
20/04/24 12:04:10 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
20/04/24 12:04:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
20/04/24 12:04:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
20/04/24 12:04:24 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
20/04/24 12:04:25 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
20/04/24 12:04:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1587709503815_0002
20/04/24 12:04:25 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
20/04/24 12:04:25 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
20/04/24 12:04:25 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = memory-mb, units = Mi, type = COUNTABLE
20/04/24 12:04:25 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = vcores, units = , type = COUNTABLE
20/04/24 12:04:26 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1587709503815_0002
20/04/24 12:04:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Watson:8088/proxy/application_1587709503815_0002/
20/04/24 12:04:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1587709503815_0002
20/04/24 12:04:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1587709503815_0002 running in uber mode : false
20/04/24 12:04:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
20/04/24 12:04:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
20/04/24 12:04:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1587709503815_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1587709503815_0002_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

20/04/24 12:04:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=7232
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=7232
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=7232
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=7405568
20/04/24 12:04:48 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
20/04/24 12:04:48 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 38.2364 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
20/04/24 12:04:48 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
20/04/24 12:04:48 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
20/04/24 12:04:48 ERROR mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Export job failed!
20/04/24 12:04:48 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export:
Export job failed!
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:445)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.exportTable(SqlManager.java:931)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Error Logs as in hadoop application tracker

```
2020-04-24 16:06:00,662 FATAL [IPC Server handler 11 on default port 51507] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1587719571504_0006_m_000000_0 - exited : java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:122)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '39  StateGov    BachelorDegree  Unmarried   Clerical    45  US  <=55K'
    at census_table.__loadFromFields(census_table.java:593)
    at census_table.parse(census_table.java:474)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "39   StateGov    BachelorDegree  Unmarried   Clerical    45  US  <=55K"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at census_table.__loadFromFields(census_table.java:527)
    ... 12 more
```

I have tried almost all possible combinations for export commmand but it didn't get the job done and now i have no idea how to proceed and what i'm doinng wrong. please help or suggest the changes.

NOTE : i'm able to import table from mysql indicating that username, password and jdbcURL that i'm using for --connnect parameters are also verified and working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be failing for many reasons, please follow this link to track the log to see why the process is failing

```
20/04/24 12:04:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Watson:8088/proxy/application_1587709503815_0002/
```

then you could see something like this

[image]

clik in logs and you should be able to see

[image]

and you could explore why the process is failing.

Comment: i re ran the jobs and have updated my question with the error logs that are recieved in hadoop job overview page. kindly help if you get any hints

Comment: You should be able to see  the logs because it could be for many reasons, maybe casting data types, dealing with null values or delimited parameters. You can't know if you can't see the logs. Regards.

Comment: unfortunately sir, whatever was there in logs i have already updated...
i didn't have anything more in system...
The application tracker URL goes down as soon as the job gets completed either success or fail. So that's the only info with me. if there's any other option to explore the job details please let me know. that would be a great help to me.

Comment: I said this before because maybe your script is fine and the problem could be in other place. I would like to help you, but if  we can't see the logs it's almost impossible. Regards.

Comment: As an advice I would recommend you to try to create another table in MySQL with all fields as varchar big enough, and see if the process ends up well, if so, you can explore the new table and check incosistency in the data and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. finallly  i  found some logs and it's actually failing due to numberFormatException as i had updated in question under application logs, but how i can solve this ?
do we have any parameters for hive export which we may utilize ?

Comment: I would try to export the data to a stage_table in MySQL with all fields as VARCHARS  big enough to place the data, afterwards I would do a data cleanset in the stage_table and then an INSERT INTO my_table SELECT ... FROM stage_table and finally DROP TABLE stage_table. I think it will work fine and faster than to try to check out the table in HDFS. Regards.

Comment: i created a stage table with schema 
```
create table census_table_stage
(
display_id varchar(100),
employment_type varchar(100),
edu_qualification varchar(100),
marital_status varchar(100),
job_type varchar(100),
working_hours_per_week varchar(100),
country varchar(100),
salary varchar(100)
);
```

now i'm able to successfully export data but all the data is going into single column display_id

Comment: i think there's some isuue with delimiter argument, hive is not able to split the record properly and thus a whole row is getting mapped unnder a single column.

Comment: You can try to fix your hive table like this: create a hive stage table with row format delimited fields terminated by ',' and insert into stage_table select from my_hive_table and then sqoop export from my stage_table with --input-fields-terminated-by ','

Comment: Thanks @Chema...
your trick worked now i'm able to import  data directly into main table as well, it must have been issue with '\t' delimiter

Comment: @Chema Thanks. I also had the similar issue. Problem was my varchar was not big enough